# What word is to child as dowry/"bride price" is to marriage?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English that denotes money set aside (or money given to the mother/father/parents) at the birth of a child designated for the upkeep of the child or as a gift to the adult the child is to become?

When you query the [Google News corpus pre-trained model](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) (3 million 300-dimension word vectors) using python here,

```
import gensim

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',
                                                        binary=True)

# What word is to child as dowry/"bride price" is to marriage?
# "dowry - marriage + child" looks like:
model.most_similar_cosmul(positive=['dowry', 'child'], negative=['marriage'])
```

you get this as an output:

```
[('toddler', 0.8820212483406067),
 ('infant', 0.8791450262069702),
 ('childs', 0.8452366590499878),
 ('chld', 0.8431567549705505),
 ('chid', 0.8396517038345337),
 ('newborn', 0.836097776889801),
 ('children', 0.8355128765106201),
 ('anganwadi_worker', 0.8350832462310791),
 ('chilren', 0.8305007219314575),
 ('Child', 0.8303987383842468)]
```

Comment: *Inheritance*? Although I suppose that does not specifically connote money given at the *birth* of the beneficiary - it more strongly connotes money given on the death of the giver. It is not a traditional social pattern in the way that dowries are, so there is probably no specific word for the practice. *Birth-money* would probably be a good candidate to coin a new phrase.

Comment: I'm going to go with Heritage™ for now.

Comment: (BTW, you guys are of exquisitely high quality for a community website.)

Answer (score 4):

- trust fund

> All babies born between September 2002 and 2 January 2011 got
>   £50-£1,000 free from the Government to save in a Child Trust Fund

https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/child-trust-fund-vouchers/

Comment: This is the most appropriate modern term (in US) that corresponds to the old-fashioned dowry. Older or alternate terms are [legacy, birthright, inheritance, bequest](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/trust/2?s=t).

Comment: Trust funds do not need to be for the benefit of new-born babies or even children. Or even individuals. And CTF's have been replaced by 'Junior ISAs' in the UK.

Comment: There are other applications for trusts, but when money is set aside for a child it is usually in the form of a trust, with trustees taking responsibility for the money before the child reaches majority. "trust fund" might also be used informally, like "college fund", without a legal trust being involved.

Comment: Another term would be "Child support" (or _maintenance_ or even just _support)._ It is regular payments (e.g., monthly) as opposed to a one-time payment.

Comment: *Legacy, inheritance* and *bequest* generally need someone to die, whereas the question (and the answer "trust fund") assumes a gift by the living.